# Is it a good practice to use node js only for frontend?

Tags: node.js

I am building an application where user interacts with a form based UI. After submitting it, it populates data to a DB. The user is providing details of some task which is to be scheduled. A scheduler then picks up the tasks. After finishing them, it updates status in the DB. After this, the user can pick up the result from the output section of the UI.

My question is: Can node js be used just for handling the frontend? What are the advantages and disadvantages of this, in general as well as specific to what I am trying to achieve?

Edit: I am asking this because, owing to the event loop nature of node, node seems to be good at delegating tasks for processing to other systems. So it does not matter whether the task is handled by node itself or some other system. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: As per my knowledge, nodejs is not meant for frontend only projects. There are several other libraries/frameworks for that e.g. jquery, angular. NodeJS provides us a platform where we can run server side code in a non-blocking manner. That's my opinion. May be others know better.

Comment: I think you might be looking for ReactJS which is used for frontend only and impressively efficient for the task it does.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for suggesting the libraries. I will go through them. I was basically thinking of using node as a backend for the frontend where the actual backend task will be done by another system. In my case it will be a sort of daemon picking up tasks from the DB and executing them. As you pointed out, this is not the right use of node but is there something incorrect in using it this way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/).

Basically it is a combination of webkit and node.js in 1 .exe.
This means you can create a normal html-structure as the UI, and use node-modules to communicate to other systems/databases. But it still looks like a normal application.